# Check whether element of array is in row of matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `array`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2])
```

And a `matrix`:

```
m = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

I want to check if `1` from `a` is in `[1, 2]` from `m` and if `2` from `a` is in `[3, 4]` from `m`.

The desired response is `array([True, False])` and the solution should be `vectorized`.

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `broadcasting` of the array `a`:

```
a = a.reshape(2, 1)
(a == m).any(axis=1)
array([ True, False])
```

Comment: I guess `np.isin(m,a).any(axis=1)` is an easier way of doing the same

Answer (score 0):

For a vectorized solution, you can use np.isin:

```
np.isin(m[:,0],a)
#array([ True, False])
```

Comment: I would like a numpy vectorized solution, sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: Sorry that is not what I was looking for, I had to check on the whole array from m not just the first column, just found an answer thank you.